# Trouble traversing xml tree with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic

I have some legacy xml that is used to create a navigation for a certain area of a website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Menu>
    <menuItem>
        <Name>About</Name>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Link>/about/index.html</Link>
        <menuItem>
            <Name>Vision</Name>
            <ID>1.1</ID>
            <Link>/about/Vision.html</Link>
        </menuItem>
        <menuItem>
        <Name>History</Name>
            <ID>1.2</ID>
            <Link>/about/history.html</Link>
            <menuItem>
                <Name>Relocation</Name>
                <ID>1.2.1</ID>
                <Link>/about/relocation.html</Link>
            </menuItem>
        </menuItem>
    </menuItem>
</Menu>
```

The website itself is built in Classic ASP so I have tried to use XPath to render out the navigation:

```
Dim objXML, strLeftNav
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
objXML.async=false
objXML.load("nav.xml")
If objXML.parseError.errorcode = 0 Then
    Dim xmlNode
    For Each xmlNode In objXML.selectNodes("*/menuItem/*")
        Set xmlNameNode = xmlNode.selectSingleNode("//Menu/menuItem/Name")
        strLeftNav = strLeftNav & "<li>" & xmlNameNode.nodeTypedValue & "</li>"
    Next
    Set xmlNameNode = Nothing
End If
Set objXML = Nothing
Response.Write("<ul>" & strLeftNav & "</ul>")
```

This leaves me with a number of li just showing the first Name node with is 'About' I am trying to pull out the Name node for each menuItem node into the list, can anybody advise me to the correct XPath syntax?

Comment: What's the problem if you simply loop through `objXML.selectNodes("//menuItem/Name")`?

Comment: I had simplified my script but being a navigation I would want to extract the link node for each menuItem and use this in a href and the Name node as the text for the <a>, so not just the Name node

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression `//Menu/menuItem/Name` does an absolute selection starting from the root of the tree. You want to select relative to your current position, which might be `Name`. However you haven't made it clear how you want to handle the recursive structure of the input XML, it's not clear what output you actually want.

Comment: Sorry, Ultimately I would like to produce an unordered list for my left hand menu, in the example below if I was on the history.html page I would like the code to show the following (but I have left lots of code out just to get the traversing done first): `<ul> <li><a href="/about/index.html">About</a><ul> <li><a href="/about/vision.html">Vision</a></li> <li class="active"><a href="/about/history.html">History</a><ul> <li><a href="/about/relocation.html">Relocation</a></li> </ul></li> </ul></li> </ul>`

Comment: Then you want `//menuItem` as suggested by @har07

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me and may help other:

```
    Set xmlNodes = xmlobj.selectNodes("//menuItem/menuItem")
    If xmlNodes.Length = 0 Then Response.Write "No results found!"
    Dim xmlItem
    For Each xmlItem In xmlNodes
        Set xmlNameNode = xmlItem.selectSingleNode(".//Name")
        Set xmlIDNode = xmlItem.selectSingleNode(".//ID")
        Set xmlLinkNode = xmlItem.selectSingleNode(".//Link")

        [use code such as xmlLinkNode.nodeTypedValue to create <ul>]

    Next
    Set xmlNodes = Nothing
```